# how to make a range() only even numbers in python3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I'm pretty new to python, and I was wondering if there's a way to edit *range(100)* so that it takes out all the odd numbers? I'm trying to make a simple "game" where you think of a number, it tells you to do some simple math and then tells you what number you're left with, and at the moment it works perfectly except if it returns an odd number you're left with a .5 at the end (not a major problem but I'd rather remove it to make it a little simpler). This is what i have at the moment:

```
import random, time

numList = range(100)

def getRandomNumber(numList):
    numIndex = random.randint(0, len(numList) - 1)
    return numList[numIndex]

def restartProg():
    print('Do you want to restart? (Y/N)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')  

secretNumber = getRandomNumber(numList)
secretNumber = str(secretNumber)
answer = int(secretNumber)/2
answer = str(answer)

while True:
    print()
    print('Think of a number between 1 and 100.')
    time.sleep(3)
    print()
    print('Now double that number.')
    time.sleep(3)
    print()
    print('Add ' + secretNumber + ' to it.')
    time.sleep(6)
    print()
    print('Now divide it by 2.')
    time.sleep(6)
    print()
    print('And finally, take away the first number you thought of.')
    time.sleep(5)
    print()
    print('Got it?')
    time.sleep(5)
    print()
    print('The number you are left with is... ' + answer + ', right?')
    print()
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

    gameDone = True

    if gameDone:
        if restartProg():
            secretNumber = getRandomNumber(numList)
            secretNumber = str(secretNumber)
            answer = int(secretNumber)/2
            answer = str(answer)
            gameDone = False
        else:
            break
```

Comment: u can use `step` in creating list from `range()` and try googling before asking...this way you will explore more

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the 3-argument form of [range](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) -- the third argument is the step size:

```
range(0, 100, 2)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks, I knew there must be an easy way to do it, but I only started learning python about a week ago

Answer (score 0):

For example the below Python code will show only even numbers

```py
for i in range(2, 11, 2):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Being as there are already several accepted answers to this 7 year old question, I could suggest including a sample of the output to help illustrate the demonstration.